# 'reply' was not declared in this scope C++

Tags: c++, string, if-statement, scope, compiler-errors

I knew that a lot of people got this error before, but I just started programming with C++, so I'm not really sure about most of the commands yet.

I am trying to create a program with the following source code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
char input[7];

std::cout << "Enter your gender (male or female):";
std::cin.getline (input, 6);

if (input == "male")
char reply[] = "Mr";

else
char reply[] = "Mrs";

std::cout << "Hello " << reply << "!\n";

return 0;
}
```

Now when I tried to compile this with my compiler (G++). I received this error:

```
StringTest.cpp: In function 'int main()':
StringTest.cpp: 16:26: error: 'reply' was not declared in this scope
```

Can you please tell me what exactly went wrong with my code? And how should I attempts to solve it?

Thank you,
Xarlexus

Answer (score 3):

It's a bit clearer if you add the (optional) braces:

```
if (input == "male")
{
    char reply[] = "Mr";
}
else
{
    char reply[] = "Mrs";
}

std::cout << "Hello " << reply << "!\n";
```

`reply` ceases to exist at the `}` that ends the block in which it is declared.  So, here, `reply` does not exist when you try to print it.

The solution here is to declare `reply` outside of the blocks, then assign to it from within the blocks:

```
char const* reply(0);

if (input == "male")
{
    reply = "Mr";
}
else
{
    reply = "Mrs";
}

std::cout << "Hello " << reply << "!\n";
```

This way, `reply` is still in scope (and still exists) on the last line when you print it.

---

Note, however, that while your program may now compile, it is still incorrect.  `input == "male"` does not do what you think:  `input` and `"male"` become pointers to C strings and the pointers are compared, not the contents of the pointed-to strings.  You need to use a string comparison function, or better yet, use `std::string`, which overloads `==` to have string comparison semantics.

A cleaner, correcter version of your program might look like so:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string input;

    std::cout << "Enter your gender (male or female):" << std::endl;

    if (!std::getline(std::cin, input))
    {
        std::cout << "Oops, something bad happened during input!" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    std::string reply;
    if (input == "male")
    {
        reply = "Mr";
    }
    else if (input == "female")
    {
        reply = "Mrs";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Your selection was invalid" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    std::cout << "Hello " << reply << "!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Xarlexus: You can't, at least not directly.  `reply` is of type `const char[3]` or `const char[4]`; it can't simultaneously be both.  You can make it a `const char*` rather than an array (which means `sizeof reply` gives you the size of a pointer, not the size of the array).  Or, since you're programming in C++, you can use `std::string`, which is more robust and flexible.

Comment: @KeithThompson, Hmm, I thinks I understand now about how reply can't be both const char[3] and const char[4]. Thanks for replying.

Answer (score 0):

`reply` exists locally within the scope of the if/else blocks. To access it outside of them, you must declare it outside of that scope.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main()
{
  std::string input;

  std::cout << "Enter your gender (male or female):";
  stdgetline(cin, input);

  std::string reply;
  if (input == "male") {
    reply = "Mr";
  }
  else {
    reply = "Mrs";
  }
  std::cout << "Hello " << reply << "!\n";

  return 0;
}
```

Note that this snippet in your original code doesn't do what you expect: `if (input == "male")`. You're comparing pointers, when you intend to compare strings. Preferably use `std::string` or even `strcmp`.

Answer (score 0):

There is an implicit block in each if/else statement so your code reads:

```
if (input == "male") {
   char reply[] = "Mr";
} else {
   char reply[] = "Mrs";
}

//  reply is not defined in this scope
```

What you really want is something that's more like this:

```
const char *reply;

if (input == "male")
  reply = "Mr";
else 
  reply = "Mrs";
```

Though I would personally write it like this:

```
const char * reply = (input == "male") ? "Mr" : "Mrs";
```

Also note that I would use `const char *` instead of the `char []` since I assume that the typical use is as an immutable string rather than a char[] which is mutable.

Answer (score 0):

`input == "male` is a meaningless comparision, since it will never be true. `input` is an array, and will decay to a *pointer* to the first element. From there on, it's pointer comparision (i.e., are `input` and `"male"` at the same address?), which just will not be true.

You want a `std::string` instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string> // <== add this

int main()
{
  std::string input; // <== change type of 'input'

  std::cout << "Enter your gender (male or female):";
  std::getline(std::cout, input); // <== use free function version

  char const* reply;
  if (input == "male") { // <== now does the correct comparision
    reply = "Mr";
  }
  else {
    reply = "Mrs";
  }
  std::cout << "Hello " << reply << "!\n";

  return 0;
}
```